# How I can make a inverted round effect in css like in the image specified

Tags: css

[image]

I used :before, but I am thinking need to exist a better method for this

```
    .btn-custom-search:before {
    content: ' ';
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -15px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 54px;
    width: 31px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: you just need to create 2 layer, one in background that goes also behind the white one, and than apply a background white to the one on the top layer

Comment: Why not just add the border-radius to the input field, and display it above the button?